# Safely require gems in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems, require

Is there a way to require a ruby gem safely so as to not raise an exception if the gem is not found?

I am looking a solution close to this:

```
if require 'hirb'
  # do some hirb related stuff
else
  # do other stuff
end
```

I want this to make sure no unnecessary gems are failing my deploys to production.

Comment: Ruby should have a `kind_of_want` command for when you don't really `require` something.

Comment: `def would_like(gemname, &block); begin; require gemname; yield; rescue LoadError; puts "Could not load #{gemname}"; end; end` :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It would probably be done like this:

```
begin
  require 'hirb'
rescue LoadError => e
  puts "could not find hirb"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use bundler, that way you can be sure your gems really will be installed.

Comment: Bundler is good for what it does but it doesn't help my situation for where I want to do this check.

Comment: Ok, i'd use Kernel.gem then to load a gem, and make sure it's a gem and not some other file.