# How to skip require in ruby?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, require

Can I conditionally skip requiring a file in Ruby?

```
begin
  require 'aws-sdk'
rescue LoadError
  puts "aws-sdk gem not found"
end

namespace :db do
  desc "import local postgres database to heroku. user and database name is hardcoded"
  task :import_to_heroku => [:environment, "db:dump_for_heroku"] do
    # code using aws-sdk gem
  end
end
```

In the above code, can I ask Ruby not to read after `rescue LoadError`
I can wrap the whole code in an conditional but that is inelegant.
I tried `next` and `return`.

EDIT: added a new question at [Can I conditionally skip loading "further" ruby code in the same file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526268/can-i-conditionally-skip-loading-further-ruby-code-in-the-same-file). sorry. Did not ask this question properly

Comment: Sure can. You can conditionally `require` something, or use a `rescue` to catch a failure to find it.

Comment: i have rescued `LoadError` but i want that if `LoadError` is executed., further code should not be executed. In the example given, the rake task `db:import_to_heroku` should not be called

Comment: See "[Safely require gems in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307785/safely-require-gems-in-ruby?rq=1)"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cancel evaluating a required Ruby file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34347134/how-to-cancel-evaluating-a-required-ruby-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i have rescued LoadError but i want that if LoadError is executed., further code should not be executed. In the example given, the rake task db:import_to_heroku should not be called

Then do:

```
begin
  require 'aws-sdk'

  namespace :db do
    desc "import local postgres database to heroku. user and database name is hardcoded"
    task :import_to_heroku => [:environment, "db:dump_for_heroku"] do
      # code using aws-sdk gem
    end
  end
rescue LoadError
  puts "aws-sdk gem not found"
end
```

Comment: nice :-) i wanted to, not wrap the whole code in an conditional. This seems like a conditional but better looking i guess. The only advantage of the previous code was that i know that 'aws-sdk' had a `LoadError`. But i can match the error message for that i guess.

Comment: was actually hoping for a ruby `syntax` what would skip loading the file. do not want to wrap or modify my main code in any way

Comment: actually wanted something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526268/can-i-conditionally-skip-loading-further-ruby-code-in-the-same-file

Comment: accepting it. even though wanted something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526268/can-i-conditionally-skip-loading-further-ruby-code-in-the-same-file. As i would use this code on production

Comment: So, you asked the question twice? Don't do that. Edit this one, phrase it correctly, and delete the other one. If a question's answer doesn't meet your needs it's OK to not accept an answer. But, most of all, take the time to think your question through, put in what is necessary for YOU to know to answer a question, such as code samples, errors received, essential data, etc.

Comment: ok. are u sure? following all these comments and threads, would give my future self a headache. And i created another question as two people told me that the question was improperly worded. After editing it, it seemed like another question

Comment: Improperly worded just means edit it and be clearer about what you want. Following two threads that are related would be worse than one. You can always flag it and ask a moderator what to do.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe add an `exit` after the log:

```
begin
  require 'aws-sdk'
rescue LoadError
  puts "aws-sdk gem not found"
  exit
end

namespace :db do
  desc "import local postgres database to heroku. user and database name is hardcoded"
  task :import_to_heroku => [:environment, "db:dump_for_heroku"] do
    # code using aws-sdk gem
  end
end
```

Also the abort function is to log and exit in the same call:

```
abort("aws-sdk gem not found")
```

Comment: I didn't know the `abort` :-)

Comment: i want to "skip" loading the file not abort. which will stop program execution

Comment: @theTinMan yes. I thought that is the idea.

Comment: @deepak from you question it seems you want to terminate the execution

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev thanks. should have picked a better example. and wording can be better. am editing the question

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev created another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526268/can-i-conditionally-skip-loading-further-ruby-code-in-the-same-file. As i think i did butcher this one. Hope this one is better worded :-)

Comment: @deepak sorry that I did missunderstand the question

Comment: Elegant.  I was able to add an entire `class` block inside `begin..rescue`.

Answer (score 0):

The "top-level return" feature [has been added](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4840).

It is now possible to use the `return` keyword at the top level, which as you say, did not work at the time the question was asked. [Further discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34347134/is-it-possible-to-conditionally-stop-ruby-from-evaluating-a-required-file-withou).