# Can I conditionally skip loading "further" ruby code in the same file?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, require

Can I conditionally skip loading "further" ruby code in the same file,
if a library (loaded via require) is not found ?

```
begin
  require 'aws-sdk'
rescue LoadError
  puts "aws-sdk gem not found"
  return #does not work. nor does next
end

# code after here should not be executed as `aws-sdk` gem was not found
puts "=== should not get executed"

namespace :db do
  desc "import local postgres database to heroku. user and database name is hardcoded"
  task :import_to_heroku => [:environment, "db:dump_for_heroku"] do
    # code using aws-sdk gem
  end
end
```

In the above code, can I ask Ruby not to load the file further after 
hitting a  `rescue LoadError`.

**Like an early return but for loading a file and not for a function.**

Need it because i have i have a rake task which needs `aws-sdk` rubygem but i use it only 
on my local machine. If `aws-sdk` is not found it does not make sense for me to load code afterwards in the same file. I guess i can split the code into smaller files and warp it in
a require call

```
if Rails.env.development?
  require 'import_to_heroku'
end
```

But do not want to warp or modify my existing code

Also, i can wrap the whole code in an conditional but that is inelegant.
A begin-rescue block is also a form of explicit control flow. 
I do not want to wrap or touch the original code is any manner

Maybe an api such as

```
require_or_skip_further_loading 'aws-ruby`
```

So i want my code to be functionally equivalent to

```
begin
  require 'aws-sdk'

  namespace :db do
    desc "import local postgres database to heroku. user and database name is hardcoded"
    task :import_to_heroku => [:environment, "db:dump_for_heroku"] do
      # code using aws-sdk gem
    end
  end
rescue LoadError
  puts "aws-sdk gem not found"
end
```

Or via an if conditional

```
library_found = false
begin
  require 'aws-sdk'
  library_found = true
rescue LoadError
  puts "aws-sdk gem not found"
  return #does not work
end

if library_found      
  namespace :db do
    desc "import local postgres database to heroku. user and database name is hardcoded"
    task :import_to_heroku => [:environment, "db:dump_for_heroku"] do
    # code using aws-sdk gem
    end
  end
end
```

**Want program execution to continue after `LoadError` is raised. ie. gracefully handle `LoadError` and do not load code written after `LoadError` in the same file. cannot raise `exit` or `abort` on `LoadError` And particularly the code after `LoadError` should not be executed (or loaded) by the ruby interpreter**

Had originally asked [How to skip require in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14522350/how-to-skip-require-in-ruby)
but i did not ask the question properly. hope this is better worded

Comment: There is no need to "skip" the rest of the file, which is anyway already "loaded". In case of `rescue LoadError`, you code terminates (with `return` or preferably `exit`) and Ruby will not process the rest of the file.

Comment: @BernardK Thanks. edited the question. Want it to be equivalent to wrapping it in a begin-rescue or if-block as asked in the question. The relevant portion is. Want program execution to continue after `LoadError` is raised. ie. gracefully handle `LoadError` and do not load code written after `LoadError` in the same file. cannot raise `exit` or `abort` on `LoadError` And particularly the code after `LoadError` should not be executed (or loaded) by the ruby interpreter

Comment: How is this file loaded ? I don't know Rake. Does it `require` your file ?

Comment: I think this is being considered for Ruby 2: http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4840. I don’t know if any implementation has made it into the Ruby 2 preview releases though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cancel evaluating a required Ruby file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34347134/how-to-cancel-evaluating-a-required-ruby-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't checked the source, but I suppose that, when you run `ruby my_file.rb` at the console, or `require/load` it from Ruby code, the file is read entirely into memory before being evaluated. I'm afraid there is no such thing as skipping a part of a file.

I had an idea with catch/throw.

requiring file (for example a Rake task ?) treq1.rb :

```
catch :aws_sdk do
    require_relative 'original'
end

puts '... continued'
```

The original file that you don't want to modify, original.rb  :

```
puts 'in original, not to be modified'
begin
  require 'aws-sdk'
rescue LoadError
  puts "aws-sdk gem not found"
  throw :aws_sdk
end

puts ">>> to execute only if 'aws-sdk' is found"

# namespace :db do ... etc
#end
```

Execution :

```
$ ruby -w treq1.rb 
in original, not to be modified
aws-sdk gem not found
treq1.rb:2:in `require_relative': method `backtrace' called on unexpected T_NODE object (0x007fd32b88e900 flags=0x381c klass=0x0) (NotImplementedError)
    from treq1.rb:2:in `block in <main>'
    from treq1.rb:1:in `catch'
    from treq1.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

Googling with the error : http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4406870
Recent post, no answer. It works in a single file, if you want to wrap your code.
Let's try another solution. Supposing that you can change the Rake task, treq2.rb :

```
begin
    require_relative 'original'
rescue LocalJumpError
    puts 'rescued LocalJumpError'
end

puts '... continued'
```

In original.rb, replace `throw :aws_sdk` by `return` :

```
$ ruby -w treq2.rb 
in original, not to be modified
aws-sdk gem not found
rescued LocalJumpError
... continued
```

This way it works.
HTH

Comment: did not understand the second example ie. using `LocalJumpError`. I Did not get any error in the first example. I am using ruby 1.9.3p327

Comment: Are you using two separate files ? Errors occur only with two files.

Comment: yes actually. the actual code (copied from your example) and the output is at https://gist.github.com/4644058. I am using MRI ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10 revision 37606) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0] Ruby installation does not have any custom patches

Comment: I have installed ruby-1.9.3-p362. Now the version with catch/throw distributed into two files works, as well as the version with return/rescue. So are you happy now ? Is it what you were looking for ?

Comment: @deepak Answer to your first comment : if you run `ruby original.rb` with a `return`, not `throw`, error `in 'rescue in <main>': unexpected return (LocalJumpError)`, but if original.rb is required from another file, we can capture the error, rescue it and continue.

Answer (score 1):

The "top-level return" feature [has been added](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4840).

It is now possible to use the `return` keyword at the top level, as in your "via an if conditional" example. [Further discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34347134/is-it-possible-to-conditionally-stop-ruby-from-evaluating-a-required-file-withou).